# Can the surface of the closed unit ball be compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

It is known that in the Banach space with infinite dimension, the closed unit ball is not compact. I am just wondering if it is possible for the surface of the ball, say $\|x\|=1$ can be compact.

Comment: For the record, the usual proof of noncompactness of unit balls exhibits an infinite family of _unit_ vectors which are pairwise separated, so the same proof actually shows the unit sphere is not compact.

Comment: Is "surface of the ball" just a complicated way to say "sphere"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, because then the closed unit ball would be compact, since it is the image of the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]\times\{x\,|\,\|x\|=1\}&\longrightarrow&\text{your space}\\(t,x)&\mapsto&tx.\end{array}$$